# Error: Undefined symbol for architecture x86_64: "OBJC_CLASS_$_InventoryItem", referenced from: objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o

Tags: objective-c, xcode

[image: This is the exact error.]

What should I do to solve this problem?  I created both the InventoryItem.h & InventoryItem.c files so I don't understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you re-created the build scheme for the project? e.g.

1) Product Menu > Schemes > Manage Schemes
   2) Delete the Scheme corresponding to your prohect
   3) Click on "Autocreate Schemes Now"

Build again.

If that doesn't work, then take a look in your build phases, and ensure that the .m file for your class is in `Compile Sources` stage.

The last thing I can think of is, are you trying to import iOS classes into a Mac app or visa-versa?

e.g. in an iOS app:

```
import Cocoa
```

e.g. in a Mac app:

```
import UIKit
```

It's highly unlikely, but this too can cause similar errors.

Comment: Hi, I tried both approaches but am still getting the same two errors: 1.) "_OBJC_CLASS_$_InventoryItem", referenced from, 2.) Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation).  What should I do now?

Comment: delete the derived data and rebuild?

Comment: I just did that by deleting the contents of ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData and closed Xcode while was closed.  I did a Clean and then Build from the Xcode Project menu.  What should I do now?  Thanks!

Comment: In the build settings, clear anything under the "Other Linker Flags". Also double-check that all of your .m files are actually in the compile build phase, specifically the InventoryItem.m (but check others too). Finally is this an iOS app or OSX?

Comment: I checked those two things but they didn't apply to me because there isn't anything to clear under the "Other Linker Flags" and my InventoryItem.m file was under the compile build phase.  Finally, it is an macOS/OSX app.